# How can I turn off GOPROXY completely

Tags: go

I would like to completely turn off GOPROXY as it is caching repositories and I cannot get latest updates from my dependencies immediately. I have tried

```
export GOPROXY=direct
```

and

```
export GOPROXY=off
```

and they are not working! because it still downloads the old version of the repository!

I also tried removing go.mod in my CI pipeline and creating it again but it is still download the old repo from it's own proxy.

What is the correct way to completely disable that proxy so that everything would be downloaded from their main branch directly?

Comment: "because it still downloads the old version of the repository" is not an actionable problem description.

Comment: @Volker: I manually clone the repo it is up to date. I do it via go get and then I check it. It is the old version.

Comment: @Volker: I also doubled checked the env, it is set properly

Comment: What should I do if I don't want that goproxy?

Comment: @Volker: It does not work on `go mod tidy`. That is why. They probably forgot to apply on when go mod tidy downloads dependencies.

Comment: For me go mod tidy works well with GOPROXY direct. If you need help you will have to show real examples like your go.mod, the exact invocation of go get, the URL of the repo and the commit you think go mod tidy or go get should download and and which ist does download. Also show the output of go mod tidy -x.

Comment: @Volker: How do you use it? can you provide an example?

Comment: GOPROXY=direct go mod tidy . Look: You have to provide the information on _your_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

To opt-out of this module mirror, you can turn it off by setting
GOPROXY=direct

https://proxy.golang.org/